# Uso de Loops para edição de dataframe [R]

Tags: r

Utilizei o pacote **wbstats** para baixar uma base de dados de Qualidade da Governança do Banco Mundial para países da América Latina. O código abaixo reproduz o processo:

```
LATAM <- c("ARG","BOL","BRA","CHL","COL","CRI","CUB","DOM","ECU","GTM","HND","HTI","MEX","NIC","PAN", "PER","PRY","SLV","URY","VEN")

WGI <- c("CC.EST", "GE.EST", "PV.EST", "RQ.EST", "RL.EST", "VA.EST")

WGI_LAT <- wb(country = LATAM, indicator = WGI)
```

Procurei editar a base usando Loops. Fiz uma matriz e transferi os valores dos respectivos indicadores para novas colunas, da seguinte forma:

```
WGI_LAT <- data.frame(WGI_LAT$country, WGI_LAT$iso3c, WGI_LAT$date, WGI_LAT$indicatorID, WGI_LAT$value)
colnames(WGI_LAT) <- c('Country', 'Country_code', 'Dates', 'WGI', 'Value')

series = c('CC.EST', 'GE.EST', 'PV.EST', 'RQ.EST', 'RL.EST', 'VA.EST')
database = matrix(NA, ncol=length(series), 
             nrow=nrow(WGI_LAT)/length(series))

for(i in 1:length(series)){
  database[,i] = WGI_LAT$Value[WGI_LAT$WGI
                         ==series[i]] 
  database = data.frame(database)
  colnames(database) = series
}
```

Ao fazê-lo dessa forma, consegui desagregar as informações dos indicadores em colunas diferentes, mas perdi as informações de países e anos. Alguém poderia me ajudar a descobrir uma forma de fazer a edição da base preservando essas informações (tal como visto no dataframe **WGI_LAT**), ou incorporando-as posteriormente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema conjugando um outro data.frame, com informações de crescimento do PIB. Ao juntar os dois data.frames, consegui gerar um data.frame final com as informações que precisava. Abaixo, segue o código:

```
GDP <- c("NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG")
GDP_LAT <- wb(country = LATAM, indicator = GDP, startdate = 1996, enddate = 2018)
GDP_LAT <- GDP_LAT[,c(2,7,3)]
colnames(GDP_LAT) <- c("Dates", "Country", "GDP")
GDP_Latam <- subset(GDP_LAT, Dates!=1997 & Dates!=1999 & Dates!=2001)

database <- data.frame(GDP_Latam, WGI_Latam)
colnames(database) <- c("Dates", "Country", "GDP", "HDI", "CC", "GE", "PV", "RQ", "RL", "VA")
```